# Is it possible to display HTML from within a PHP class?

Tags: php

Is it possible to write a form and javascript validations using class and functions. Her is my code sample.

```
class files{

  function displayhtml(){?> 

select name="df" onchange=analert(this.value);>

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){?>

         <option value="<?php echo "$i"; ?>"><?php echo "$i"; ?></option><?php
        }?></select><?php
  }
}
echo files::displayhtml();
?>
```

On change event i need to alert the value selected in dropdown, how will i write javascript in this same class. ???

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think you're looking for this:

```
<?php

class file {
    public static function displayHTML() {
        $result  = "<form><select onchange='alert(this.value)'>";
        for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
            $result .= "<option value='".$i."'>".$i."</option>";
        }
        $result .= "</select></form>";
        return $result;
    }
}

echo file::displayHTML();
?>
```

Comment: I suspect 'work' have some problems separating PHP, HTML and JS into their respective technologies. Simple answer; you can simply use echo of any output you like, including JavaScript, or return it like this example above. What about all of this is it that you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

in event onchange must : `onchange="alert(this.value)"`

Comment: where will i write this javascript inside class